# Updating the original HashSet by intersecting with other HashSet, instead of creating a new HashSet

Tags: rust, intersection

The Rust's `HashSet::intersection` function creates a new HashSet. How can I update original HashSet by the result of intersection of two HashSets?

```
fn main() {
    // intersecting two HashSets, creating a new HashSet: OK
    use std::collections::HashSet;
    let a = HashSet::from(["first", "second", "third"]);
    let b = HashSet::from(["first", "third", "fifth", "ninth"]);
    let intersection: HashSet<_> = a.intersection(&b).collect();
    println!("{:?}", intersection);

    
    // intersecting two HashSets, updating the original HashSet: Failed
    let mut a = HashSet::from(["first", "second", "third"]);
    let b = HashSet::from(["first", "third", "fifth", "ninth"]);
    println!("{:?}", a.intersection(&b).collect::<HashSet<_>>());
    println!("{:?}", a);
    a = a.intersection(&b).collect::<HashSet<_>>();  // doesn't work

    // filter: verbose
    let mut a = HashSet::from(["first", "second", "third"]);
    let b = HashSet::from(["first", "third", "fifth", "ninth"]);
    a = a.iter().filter(|&s| b.contains(s)).map(|s| *s).collect::<HashSet<_>>();
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this without allocating a new `HashSet`, you can use `HashSet::retain` and only retain the elements that exist in the second `HashSet`:

```rust
fn main() {
    use std::collections::HashSet;
    let mut a = HashSet::from(["first", "second", "third"]);
    let b = HashSet::from(["first", "third", "fifth", "ninth"]);
    println!("{:?}", a.intersection(&b).collect::<HashSet<_>>());
    a.retain(|x| b.contains(x));
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Output:

```
{"third", "first"}
{"first", "third"}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=781b33b258bab19e62b0b5d8135f1f75)

Comment: Thank you, the `retain` function is exactly what I wanted.